# Find last Row in Access report Column

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

I have a report that generates with three columns, these columns are not data columns but columns of records.

I need to add a solid black line to the end of each column. This will complete a box around the outside of each column in the report.

I know how to add the line in the event `Detail_Print` but can't figure out how to detect that the record is the last in any column.

Additionally the heights of the rows vary due to `canGrow` turned on one of the fields, so I can't count the rows and then and keep track of the current count to figure it out.

Thanks for the help.

**EDIT - Additional Question**

Is there a way to determine the available height for the detail section, like the number of twips between the 'bottom of the page header' and the 'top of the page footer' Because I think I can do it if I know that value or can derive it somehow.

Comment: How about concatenating another row, which has a key of 99999999 or some such value higher than all keys in your tables. And detect that in DetailPrint, and remove it, and replace it with your solid black line.   (sql=  Select .... from ...  UNION ALL  Select "99999999" ...)

Comment: @donPablo that only gives me the last row on the last column, that is the only one that I can get, I am after the last row on each column. So making an extra row in the data is not going to help really.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of two solutions.

1) put the data in each column into a separate sub-report, and simply mark the sub-reports as having solid borders: problem solved, though it will make the report a bit messy to create and maintain.

2) The report must have a record source. Don't set the record source in the properties window, set it in the report_open event.

Before setting the record source, determine how many rows are represented by the record source, and put this information in a variable, and in the Detail_Format event, count the rows, using another variable; On the row where the row counter = the number of rows, put the line.

For example;

if the record source is

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM myTable WHERE col1 = 'Purple'
```

then the number of rows is

```
SELECT count(*) FROM myTable WHERE col1 = 'Purple'
```

Comment: I understand the implementation of what you are suggesting but that is not going to work in this case as this is one really long list that is flowing from column 1 to 2 to 3 then onto the next page where it starts again. I can't see these solutions working but thanks anyway

Comment: @Bullfrog What is the record source of the report, and what columns/fields of the record source show in the columns?

Comment: A query is the recordset,

Comment: Sorry for delay been away, A query is the record source, three columns, "First Letter of last Name, Name String, Department. Each of these columns are displayed on the report. The report is grouped by the first letter column then the name column, in case someone is in two departments. There is a requirement that the report must fit on one double sided A4 piece of paper. That is the reason for the multiple columns. Names currently wrap in some rows due to really large names. This is the reason that I can't use the method of just x number of rows add a line.

Comment: I'm guessing you want the column outlines at the top and bottom of the page, and not where the last record prints in the last column? The whole thing sounds jolly difficult. You could try removing the detail section and putting this into a subreport with no header or footer, and putting the subreport into the existing report's detail section with a line hard above and another hard below - but that's only good for one page of data, and if you're showing lines between the columns it's unlikely to work in the last column after the last line of data. I think I can only say "Good Luck"!

Comment: Thanks, for the help. I am slowly trying different things. I will post back if I get it, but I suggest no one holds their breath as I may never get it.